# Memory Leak: Visual Studio 2013/PRISM 5/Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2013, memory-leaks, prism, windows-7-x64

I'm experiencing a pretty serious memory leak when running WPF 4.5/PRISM 5.0 projects in Visual Studio 2013 on my Windows 7 (64-bit) machine. This has been going on for months and I've tried to narrow it down. The only common denominator is the parameters I've already noted.

It's not any particular WPF/PRISM project that causes the issue. I first noticed the problem when trying out code from various WPF demos on PluralSight and elsewhere. Initially, I had only 8GB RAM on my machine and Windows notified me that I had to shut something down or I'd run out of RAM. I've since upgraded to 16GM RAM and I can run projects for a few extra days without rebooting my machine. Logging off doesn't help. Simply shutting down every running application and waiting (even over night) does not help.

When reviewing the Processes (including the ones for All Users), no process sticks out as taking up the extra memory and what's listed doesn't come close to adding up to what's being taken up in memory. The memory seems to slowly creep up after multiple runs of any WPF/PRISM projects in VS2013. Eventually, I'll find there are gigs(!) of orphaned memory being used up that I can't recover.

I've searched online for any known issues and can find none. I don't know how to nail down the exact culprit either.

Anyone else experiencing this? Any ideas on how I can find out exactly what's causing it and/or how to fix it? I'd rather not have to uninstall/reinstall VS2013, but as a last resort, I suppose I can try it. My luck it will be futile though.

Comment: this is how I found my memory leak: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19490/Memory-Leak-Detection-in-NET

Comment: You could try using a memory profiler to figure out a particulat memory leak. In our Prism based solution, we use some memory consuming image processing algorithms, and we don't observe any significant memory leaks.

Comment: Try going through Maoni's Weblog. There are articles to nail down problems. I dont remember the exact one so giving link of complete weblog - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/maoni/